# Why I am getting Asp.net Default Page in return when calling web API controller created within same project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

1- Accessing Web Api but getting default Page in return
2- Added Asp.net Api project in Existing Web forms application.
[Using this Microsoft Artical](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms)
3- When Calling Url through Postman returning Landing Page of application.

I have tried with Fiddler and Postman but not returning my desired result.

Postman Request

[image: Postman Request]

Project Structure

[image: Project Structure]

You can check my project structure and My request and Response using PostMan..

Comment: Please post your code so we can understand better what problem you are encountering?

Comment: Please also explain what it means to "*Added Asp.net Api project in Existing Web forms application*". Did you add Web API to the webforms project or did you add a whole separate project to your solution?

Comment: Only Web Api project in existing Asp.net web forms project.